# Is triggered send data inaccurate in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, triggered-send, history-tracking, sfmc-business-unit

Previously to search and confirm if a customer received a triggered email, I would go to that particular trigger and input the customer's email within the specific date range for that trigger. This information was, to the best of my knowledge, accurate every time. However, upon my most recent search, Marketing Cloud said that we didn't send a triggered send to a customer, when our API call confirms we did. Is this an error in Marketing Cloud, and if so is there a more accurate way to confirms sends to a particular email past 6 months?

Comment: Where exactly in Marketing Cloud do you check?

Comment: I go to Email Studio>sends>Triggered Sends>Click on the particular triggered sends>Set date>search email address within that set date

Comment: What API call is being used to confirm that an email did get sent?

Comment: Please do note that an API call can complete successfully to send the data to the Trigger Send, but then a syntax error or some other filtering process may prevent the message from entering the send queue and being sent. Therefore your API would say it was sent, but the tracking would not show it.

Comment: We're using a SOAP API for the triggered data send. Thanks @Gortonington. If the triggered send data does pull up a specific email address when you search in the sent hyperlink, does that confirm that was the email address it was sent to? Or is it possible for that data to be incorrect?

Comment: If you mean inside the tracking tab for the Trigger Send, if you search for a subscriber there and they show up, does this mean they were sent to? The answer is yes. The sent section there are those that went through the send queue. Now if there was something that prevented the delivery, then it could not have shown up in the inbox - but SFMC did send it.

Comment: @Gortonington Have you ever seen it where we confirmed it was delivered, but did not show up in the send inbox? That's essentially the problem I'm running into. Never had seen it before